# Values of a graph

Tags: javascript, svg, graph

I have a pentagon graph made up with SVG coding. So I made the pentagon with codes like so:

```
 <svg><path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,-62.5 L60.5,-18.5 L37.5,51.5 L-36.5,51.5 L-59.5,-18.5 L0.5,-62.5 M0,0 L0,0"></svg>
```

Right now, on a graph perspective, the pentagon is showing values of 30 for each side. I am trying to find a way to change the values without always having to go inside PATH CS to change the degree values.

Anyone have an idea, I have been looking it up and found that connecting it with a javascript would be the best case but I have no idea how to write the proper javascript. Could anyone help?

Comment: what is this `cs` attribute? I can't find anything…

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it answers your question. I don't understand what is cs property neither what you really want to modify.

But, here is a way (maybe not the best) to access all your polygon's points by javascript :

You can set all your `d` points into an array of array, then access each point by modifying it

```js
var p = document.querySelector('path');

var a = [
  [ ["M"],[0.5, -62.5] ],
  [ ["L"],[60.5, -18.5] ],
  [ ["L"],[37.5, 51.5] ],
  [ ["L"],[-36.5, 51.5] ],
  [ ["L"],[-59.5, -18.5] ],
  [ ["L"],[0.5, -62.5] ],
  [ ["M"],[0, 0] ],
  [ ["L"],[0, 0] ]
];


function draw() {
    //loop through the array to join path descriptions with their values
    var d = function(){var r = '';for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) r += a[i].join('') + " "; return r;};
    p.setAttribute('d', d());
  }

//EXAMPLes
  //Change each value manually then redraw
p.addEventListener('click', function() {
  a[1][1][0] ++;
  a[2][1][1] --;
  draw();
}, false);

  //a simple function to change values of set points
function move(point, xy, newValue) {
  a[point][1][xy] = newValue;
  draw();
}
window.onclick = function() {
  move(2, 0, 75);
};
```

```html
<svg>
  <path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,-62.5 L60.5,-18.5 L37.5,51.5 L-36.5,51.5 L-59.5,-18.5 L0.5,-62.5 M0,0 L0,0">
</svg>
```

If you won't change the structure (number of points) of your polygon, then you can use a simpler structure :

```js
var p = document.querySelector('path');

    var a = [
      [0.5, -62.5],
      [60.5, -18.5],
      [37.5, 51.5],
      [-36.5, 51.5],
      [-59.5, -18.5],
      [0.5, -62.5],
      [0, 0],
      [0, 0]
    ];

    function draw() {
      //HardWrite the path descriptions
      p.setAttribute('d', "M" + a[0] + " " + "L" + a[1] + " " + "L" + a[2] + " " + "L" + a[3] + " " + "L" + a[4] + " " + "L" + a[5] + " " + "M" + a[6] + " " + "L" + a[7]);
    }

     //Change each value manually then redraw
    p.addEventListener('click', function() {
      a[1][0] ++;
      draw();
    }, false);

     //a simple function to change values of set points
    function move(point, xy, newValue) {
      a[point][xy] = newValue;
      draw();
    }
    window.onclick = function(){ move(2, 0, 75);};
```

```html
<svg>
  <path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,-62.5 L60.5,-18.5 L37.5,51.5 L-36.5,51.5 L-59.5,-18.5 L0.5,-62.5 M0,0 L0,0">
</svg>
```